# How to open a file without typing its entire name?

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, command-line-interface, cd

I want to be more comfortable with CLI, so I need practice. :D

I have a directory and within it I have more of them. I use `ls` to find their name, but the one I want to change into has a very long name.

Is it possible to change to that directory without typing his entire name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to type few chars of that name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once to complete that name.
If it doesn't complete, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to see available names that start with the character sequence that you entered. Then, add few more chars, so that sequence is unique for that name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete.